# How to go about proving the following Identity?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I need to prove the following Identity, but I'm completely lost on how to do it. $$\left(\frac{a}{b^k}\right)^{log_{b}n} = \frac{n^{log_{b}a}}{n^k}$$

I also didn't come very far. I tried working on both left side and right side. But when taking the left side I get to this:
$$\frac{a^{log_{b}n}}{n^k} = \frac{n^{log_{b}a}}{n^k}$$

But that would mean that it's true only if a = n

Comment: **Hint :** $$a^{\log_b(n)} = e^{\frac{\ln(n)\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}} = n^{\log_b(a)}$$ where $\ln$ denotes the natural logarithm.

Comment: RHS appears to be $\dfrac{n^{\log_{b}(a)}}{n^{k}}$.